# Google settings permanent uninstall

Tags: uninstallation, google-settings

Is it possible to permanently uninstall the **Google Settings** application?

**update**
Thanks for reply!
My device is `LG Optimus Me`, Android version `2.2.2`, rooted

My problem has 2 aspects:
**1.** *Simple technical*. Due to quite low internal memory of device I had `memory low` message after automatically installing `Google settings`. I solve this problem by moving applications to SD card. I did it before manually, but after installing `app2sd` I found that I miss some movable applications.
**2.** *Vague psychological*. I know, it's quite stupid, but I feel that my device is out of control in some way. Someone can decide what apps to install on my device and I can do nothing with it. I understand that it's part of (eco)system, but I don't feel that I need that `settings`. Also it's not very lightweight in terms of size. Maybe I'm too paranoid?..

Comment: I would not uninstall it -- it will always "come back" (i.e. automatically re-install) I assume. If it disturbs you, you might try to disable it: *Settings->Apps->Manage Apps*, scroll to it, open the entry, press the "Disable" button.

Comment: As Mattlin just pointed out: It looks like *Google Settings* is part of *Google Play Services*. I wouldn't touch those, as it would lead to a bunch of side effects especially for (but not restricted to) the *Google Playstore* app.

Comment: Why do you need to uninstall Settings?  Please tell us what problem you were trying to solve, and perhaps we can think of a different and less disruptive solution than disabling a core system service.  It would also help to know which device you have, and which Android OS version it's running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a system service, not a standalone application. It is "Google Play Services". Can't uninstall system services without root privileges. If you do so with root privileges it may cause problems with Google Play.

**Settings** > **Apps** > **All** > click on **Google Play Services** and uninstall updates will work, but it will uninstall only updates. It will update automatically again by Google.

Comment: Mattlin, it's *not* *Google Play Services*. The Settings app is something quite new. It belongs into the same category, however (Google Apps).

Comment: `Appinfo` for that "`Google Settings`" icon leads to `Google Play Services`

Comment: Ooops? I never checked that (and right: there's no separate item in *Settings->Apps->Manage Apps*). So it might be *part* of *Google Play Services*. I agree with you to *not* recommend to uninstall/disable that due to side effects to be expected. And not only with *Google Playstore*...

Comment: Perhaps if we knew what problem the OP was trying to solve in the first place, we could recommend a solution that doesn't involve possible bricking of his device :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try to return your google play version to its "factory" version by going to `Settings -> Manage apps -> Google play(store)` and then uninstall updates. Usually the `factory` version of play store doesn't have the update service.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert here, but I too had the same problem with my Samsung Galaxy Pro, it has little internal memory, and the Google settings app keeps coming back. At first it was just 3 MB and now it is more than 17 MB.

It says that it is used to update Google apps and apps from Google Play. This component gives you access to Google Settings and helps apps speed up offline searches, provide more immersive maps, and improve performance.
Apps may not work if you uninstall Google Play services. You probably need this component.

Frankly, I uninstalled it everytime my phone memory is low, and now its gone, and I haven't seen any side effects, maybe because I don't use any app that needs it, I don't know, and I use google maps, gmail, and app store.